# pandas: create a caption with to_latex?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I am exporting a table from a pandas script into a .tex and would like to add a caption.

`with open('Table1.tex','w') as tf:
    tf.write(df.to_latex(longtable=True))`

(I invoke the longtable argument to span the long table over multiple pages.)

The Table1.tex file gets imported into a bigger LaTeX document via the \import command. I would like to add a caption to the table, ideally on its top. Do you think there would be any way for doing that?

I cannot manually edit the Table1.tex, it gets updated regularly using a Python script.

Comment: I think this can be done by adding `\caption{my caption}\\ ` to the second line of the latex code. So try this `tf.write(df.to_latex(longtable=True).replace('\n', '\n\\caption{my caption}\\\\\n', 1))`

Comment: This works. Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.0, released on 29 January 2020, `to_latex` accepts `caption` and `label` arguments.